# Facing difficulty in adding List<Packet> to List<List<Packet>>?

Tags: c#

I am facing problem in adding a `List<Packet>` to `List<List<Packet>>` using `.Add` method. I am using a nested for loop and when it exits the `List<List<Packet>>` has all entries filled with the last `List<Packet>` iterated in last loop. It is replacing all older values, I debugged the code and watched this happening. What is the correct way to do it?

This is the code I'm using:

```
static List<List<Packet>> generateRandomLists()
        {
            List<Packet> myList = getListOfItems();
            object syncLock = new object();
            int randomNo;

            List<List<Packet>> lists = new List<List<Packet>>();
            List<Packet> temp = new List<Packet>();
            const int SIZE = 10;
            for (int i = 0; i<SIZE ; i++)
            {
                temp.Clear();
                const int THRESHOLD = 48;
                for (int j = 0; getWeightOfBag(temp)<THRESHOLD; j++)
                {
                    lock(syncLock)
                    {
                        randomNo = rand1.Next(0, myList.Count);
                        Console.Write("{0}, ", randomNo);
                    }
                    temp.Add(myList[randomNo]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                lists.Add(temp);
            }
            return lists;
        }
```

Comment: You need to make `syncLock` a member variable, otherwise all threads calling this method will get their own object to lock on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using same instance of `temp` and you want to create new instance each time:

instead of

```
temp.Clear();
```

do

```
List<Packet> temp = new List<Packet>();
```